Do not display the footer and header during loading
I don't want <Header /> and <Footer /> to be drawn when loading in ProtectedRoutes component.
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
      const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

      useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
          setUser(currentUser)
          setLoading(false)
        })

        return () => unsubscribe()
      }, [])

      if (loading) {
        return <Loader />
      }

      return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
    }

    const App = () => {
      return (
        <Router>
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Header />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path="/pricing" element={<Price />} />
            <Route element={<PublicRoutes />}>
              <Route path="/registration" element={<Registration />} />
             <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            </Route>
            <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
              <Route path="/account" element={<Account />} />
              <Route path="/verify-email" element={<EmailVerification />} />
              <Route path="/user-files" element={<FileStorage />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </Router>
      )
    }

I want only my <Loader /> component to be displayed when loading on the page.

If you move the header and footer to wrap the Outlet You should get the behaviour your are looking for.
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return user ? (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" />
  );
};

